# How to count the difference between two nested lists in Python?

Tags: python

If I had the two following lists with tuples in the form of (x,y):

```
 [(a,1),(b,2),(c,7),(d,1)]
 [(a,3),(b,2),(c,7),(d,8)]
```

I want to count the number of differences with respect to 'y' value for corresponding 'x' values. In the above case, the answer is 2

*(a,**1**)* doesn't match with *(a,**3**)*

*(d,**1**)* doesn't match with *(d,**8**)*

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, the position of the elements matter. I want to check if element 1 in list 1 is same as element 1 in list 2 and so on.

Comment: this might have been answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138015/python-comparing-two-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python find difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559627/python-find-difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: THis is not a duplicate. I am trying to do something different here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` function and a generator expression within `sum` function :

```
count=sum(i!=j for i,j in zip(list1,list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is

```
x = [("a", 1) ,("b", 2), ("c", 7), ("d", 1)]
y = [("a", 3), ("b", 2), ("c", 7), ("d", 8)]
count = len(set(x).intersection(y))
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account position does it? (that x[1] != y[1]), just that there is a difference somewhere in x respective to y?